# Laravel Url in anchor tag

Tags: laravel

Please help me with this syntax:

```
return '<a href="{{url('admin/view_experience'}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> View</a>';
```

I have issues with quotes. I have tried:

```
return '<a href="{{ url('."admin/view_experience".'}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> View</a>';
```

But it is not working, any ideas?

Comment: Please try return '<a href="{{url(\'admin/view_experience\'}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> View</a>';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the right way:

```
return '<a href="' . url('admin/view_experience') . '" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> View</a>';
```

Comment: @VladimirStus Please stop asking for upvotes. Soliciting votes or offering to trade them with other users is not allowed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: its imortant to up vote my questions so i can contribute to society better